# Web service call through url

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

So, I've made this web service(well WCF Service I guess) that inputs some parameters and returns a json object. This works pretty well.

But now I want to make some changes to the client.

Currently I just have a button, some textboxes for inputs, and a textarea.

The button looks like this:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client sc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
protected void Button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int? i;
    if (tbSagsNr.Text != "")
    {
        i = Convert.ToInt32(tbPOSTUdlSag.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        i = null;
    }
    string s = tbFacilitet.Text;
    string a1 = tbAdresse1.Text;
    string a2 = tbAdresse2.Text;
    string p = tbPostNr.Text;

    string json = sc.HouseSearch(i, s, a1, a2, p);

    TextArea1.InnerText = json;
}
```

What do I do if I want to call the web service through the url instead? I'm thinking it should look something like this, depending on what parameters I use:

```
http://localhost:58637/Default.aspx/Service1.svc/HouseSearch?vSagsNr=5
```

Instead of textboxes and all that it should just print the json string directly on the screen.

I'm pretty new at making web services and I feel like I've kinda just been bumbling my way so far.

IService1:

```
    [OperationContract()]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "HouseSearch")]
    string HouseSearch(int? vSagsNr, string vFacilitet, string vAdresse1, string vAdresse2, string vPostNr);
```

Edit: Actually it should look more like this probably:

```
http://localhost:58637/WCFTest3/Service1.svc/HouseSearch?vSagsnr=5
```

Edit: My webconfig now looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFTest3_Behavior" name="WCFTest3.Service1">
        <endpoint
            address =""
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBinding"
            name="WCFTest3.Service1"
            contract="WCFTest3.IService1"
            behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFTest3_Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="UnikBoligCon"
      connectionString="server=??;database=??;user=??;password=??"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But I get this error:

```
No base address found that matches the https form for the endpoint with the WebHttpBinding link. Registered base address schemas are [http].
```

Edit: Oh wait I guess I need to fill in the adress, services in the webconfig now looks like this

```
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFTest3_Behavior" name="WCFTest3.Service1">
        <endpoint
            address ="http://localhost:58532/Service1.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBinding"
            name="WCFTest3.Service1"
            contract="WCFTest3.IService1"
            behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
```

And I've gotten rid of "multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"" because it threw an error and I don't think I need it.

Now getting this error though:

```
The authentication schemes configured on the host (Anonymous) do not allow those configured on the binding WebHttpBinding (“Anonymous”). Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly. Additionally, this may be resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application through the IIS management tool, through the ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the application configuration file at the element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding, or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the HttpTransportBindingElement.
```

Comment: Take a look at System.Net.WebClient and the DownloadString method. I think that should do what you need.

Comment: @DerKejser For the latest errors - Anonymous and the Security mode, I think you need to disable Anonymous Access and enable Windows Authentication, all done via IIS and the Authentication section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something much the same as you described. A WCF service that can be switched (by changing the web.config) to serve Http, NetTCP, or REST. It was easy enough to get Http and NetTCP configs to sit side by side, but I was unable to figure out how to incorporate the REST config with the other two, so I kept them separate (and my requirements didn't call for a REST api, I just wanted to do it anyway).

My Operation Contract is:

```
[OperationContract]
[
 WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "TestMethod/{applicationCode}/?ignoreStatus={ignoreStatus}&logonName={logonName}&userProfileId={userProfileId}")
]
String TestMethod(String applicationCode, Boolean ignoreStatus = false, String logonName = "", String userProfileId = "");
```

Which can be called via a Url (tested using an Internet Browser).

```
http://localhost/JayVServerV2/DataAccess/DataAccess.svc/TestMethod/Tom?ignoreStatus=true&logonName=JayV&userProfileId
```

The most important part of the solution was getting the Web.Config setup correctly. So, I have included the whole of my Web.Config for you to see how I did it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="JayVServer_Behavior" name="JayVServerV2.DataAccess.DataAccess">
            <endpoint
                address =""
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBinding"
                name="RestJayVServerV2.DataAccess.DataAccess"
                contract="DataServerV2.DAtaAccess.IDataAccess"
                behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="JayVServer_Behavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpEndpointBinding">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've updated my post with another question.